# Panic fault when mounting LVM2 volume

Tags: centos, lvm, data, xfs

I have a CentOS 7 system that I can boot using a live cd.

The system HDD's have an lvm2 partition with 2 volumes /root and /home.

I can mount /root volume without any problems in the live environment.

When I attempt to mount the /home volume it results in a kernel panic.

I need to mount the /home directory if only temporarily to copy the files off.

Edit: Addition Info:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos_midas/swap' [3.64 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos_midas/home' [877.32 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos_midas/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
[root@localhost ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdb2   VG centos_midas   lvm2 [930.96 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [930.96 GiB] / in use: 1 [930.96 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
[root@localhost ~]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "centos_midas" using metadata type lvm2
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Please provide details on the panic... also which filesystems are you using.

Comment: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000009B" iirc they are ext4 w/ lvm2.

Comment: I take it back, fstab lists the file system as xfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran:

```
xfs_repair -L /dev/centos_midas/home
```

And was able to mount the volume and copy the files off to an external USB drive.